# SyntaxError remaining/shifting between lines in py file

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have eight dataframes created with similar attributes except for source files/worksheets.  At a line starting with 'df3' I am receiving a syntax error.  The line starting with 'df3' is the same in structure as every other dataframe.  If I comment block-out the line 'df3' the syntax error shifts to the next dataframe line below 'df4'.  If I comment block-out the line 'df4' the syntax error shifts to df5.  What could be causing this type of error when the syntax is all the same and all but one dataframe is receiving the syntax error?  I am using pydev in eclipse.

I've tried to place '#' before various lines of code to try to eliminate the line with the error, but the syntax error moves to the next dataframe line.

```
 df3 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\SBF\Desktop\Code\STAT\DataBook.xlsx', sheet_name = 'sheet_3', usecols = [0,2,3,5,6,9,10], header = 3)
 df4 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\SBF\Desktop\Code\STAT\DataBook.xlsx', sheet_name = 'sheet_4', usecols = [0,2,3,5,6,9,10], header = 3)
 df5 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\SBF\Desktop\Code\STAT\DataBook.xlsx', sheet_name = 'sheet_5', usecols = [0,2,3,5,6,9,10], header = 3)
```

error message 'SyntaxError' starts on line 'df3', then shifts to line 'df4' when 'df3' is blocked with '#'.  shifts to line 'df5' when 'df3' and 'df4' are comment blocked with '#'  It doesn't look like the syntax error is accurate because of the similar format of the lines of code and the fact that it is moving through lines of code without discrimination.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without a complete example, but I'm guessing the error is in the line *before* this (e.g. missing a close-paren). The parser then throws an error when it seems something unexpected, namely, an assignment statement inside a set of parentheses.

Comment: spot on, there was a missing parentheses in the line above the error.  I didn't think to check the line above when the syntax error pointed to the line below.